# How to change the template default.html in Dreamweaver CS 5.5 and keep </head> tabbed?

Tags: templates, dreamweaver

I've changed the default template default.html located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CS5.5\configuration\DocumentTypes\NewDocuments.

I want it to look like this when creating new .html pages:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

But DW keeps putting the head-closing-tag to the left so it ends up like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I read your question and thought, 'Does it really matter?'

You do not intend to indent the `<html>` tag, so why indent `<head>` and `<body>`, as they are so distinct, anyway?

I think it is preferable to have the indentation go something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This way would reduce the need for sideways scrolling or wordwrapping, while everything will be as clear to read as your intended format, (if not more so, as there is a clearer separation between the head and body).

Comment: Ok you got a point there, but if youre to be exact the head and body is nested within the htmltag, right?

Comment: @Chris_45: Yeah, sure, but the whole point is making it clear to read, and this way is clearer, anyway.  There is no technical need for the indentation.  Just forget the `<html>` tag is even there.